# How to ignore left padding in a LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I'm modifying code for an ID search bar and I'm trying to enable the user to be able to search for ID's using SQL syntax, so for example '%535%'. Doing just that is simple enough, but I've been searching and racking my brains for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution to the issue described below:

The problem is that the IDs are all left-padded varchar(14), as in:

```
'          8534'
'        393583'
'    123456/789'
```

This virtually disables the user from searching **only** for IDs that begin with a certain sequence, as '85%' returns no results due to the whitespace padding.

The site I'm maintaining is an oldie written in classic ASP (w/ JScript) and the search is done via a stored procedure with the whole 'WHERE' clause being passed in as a parameter.

I'm not able to modify the database, so what I"m asking is: is there any way to modify the clause so that the padding is ignored and '52%' returns IDs beginning with 52?

Comment: Answered below but i could apply it to your query if you showed it.

Comment: I think you would want 52% to return entries starting with 52, not %52

Comment: The query is hidden in the stored procedure and returns columns based on a layout table, so what I'm passing in is just the WHERE clause, which is dynamically built using data from the column headers, which contain textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in the where clause tend to be slow.  Something like this might be quicker:

```
where id like '123%'
or id like '% 123%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT LTRIM(ID) FROM table WHERE ID LIKE '%1234%'
```

Edit as you can only modify WHERE statement

```
WHERE LTRIM(ID) LIKE '1234%'
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer @Matt! Unfortunately I can't modify the select statement itself, just the WHERE clause. Since the IDs are stored as described in the question, searching with '%1234%' gives me all items containing '1234', not just the ones **beginning** with it. Basically what I need is for the user to type in '1234%' and for it to return
`'          1234'`
`'         12345'`
but not `'         01234'`

Comment: This will work, but realize that your query will not be using any indexes in this search.  It will have to look at every row in the table for each query.  If the table is large, it is going to be quite slow.  The best way to do it would be to add a persisted computed column to the table that has the LTRIM on that field.  Next best would be an indexed view, but both of those will require changes to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
where ltrim(id) like '123%'
```

or, assuming that there are no interior spaces in the id:

```
where concat(' ', id) like '% 123%'
```